# How to check whether a username is being used on Twitter without being rate limited?

Tags: twitter

There are many REST API methods to check if a username is being used on Twitter but as far as I researched all of them are rate limited.

The reason I want this feature is to prevent someone from claiming a username on a *website* that someone else uses on Twitter, for example someone might claim a celebrity's username and confuse people.

It's impossible to use oauth in this scenario, since the user in this scenario might not be a Twitter user.

[150/hour rate limit is unacceptable. A possible solution would be to use Bing Search API to search for the username? - If Bing Search is not rate limited of course]

Comment: what if a person has the same name as a celebrity on twitter ?

Comment: If a username has >40 followers, I would reserve that username for that user, if a person has the same name, would want to use that name as a username on *website*, he/she could only do it after giving twitter oauth permissions and verifying he/she owns the username on Twitter too, hope this clears everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try curl, here is minimal working script in php:

```
$url = "http://mobile.twitter.com/justinbieber";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($code == 200)
{
    echo "He is on twitter";
}
else 
{
    echo "He is on not twitter";
}
```

*You should query mobile.twitter.com instead of real one, because real one doesn't do HTTP response codes. and few more reasons.*

Comment: thanks for the answer izeed, do they block requests to mobile.twitter? lets say at a 10/second rate?

Comment: No - its public webpage. Your IP might get banned if their servers start chocking because of you, but that is improbable.